# recursive push only adds last element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that generates all combinations of elements in a list for a given length and returns them in a 2D list (e.g. elements [1, 2, 3] and length 2 results in [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], ...]) but am having issues implementing this function. The resulting list is the correct length but all items in the list are the last one found (so for the above I get [[3, 3], [3, 3], [3, 3], ...]).

I believe this is because JavaScript is not pushing immediately and only pushes at the end of the function so the object has already mutated, but cannot think of a way around this. How can I get it to push immediately?

```
function combinationRecursive(maxLength, position, current, elements) {
    if (position >= maxLength) {
        combinations.push(current);
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        current[position] = elements[i];
        combinationRecursive(maxLength, position + 1, current, elements);
    }
    return;
}

// example usage
combinations = [];
// max length 2 using 1,2,3 as described above
// the 0 and [] are the default starting parameters. I plan to add a wrapper function later
combinationRecursive(2, 0, [], [1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reusing the same array and at the end you get the same array in all items of the result.

You could push a copy of the array instead of the original array with the same object refernce.

```js
function combinationRecursive(maxLength, position, current, elements) {
    if (position >= maxLength) {
        combinations.push(current.slice());
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        current[position] = elements[i];
        combinationRecursive(maxLength, position + 1, current, elements);
    }
}

// example usage
combinations = [];
// max length 2 using 1,2,3 as described above
// the 0 and [] are the default starting parameters. I plan to add a wrapper function later
combinationRecursive(2, 0, [], [1, 2, 3]);

console.log(combinations);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```